# Wrong records when filtering date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have strange problem when i filter in related models by date, 
consider this code :

```
function applyDepositOnRangeFilter($query, $request)
{
    if ($request->has('deposit_at_from')) {
        $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->input('deposit_at_from'));
        });
    }


    if ($request->has('deposit_at_to')) {
        $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->input('deposit_at_to'));
        });
    }
}
```

if I filtering yesterday date  17/02/20;  it returns results with today date 18/02/20 too
and if I filter 16/02/20 it returns 17 and 18 too, 
its happens in all related model filtering only

Comment: What are the date format you are passing?

Comment: Remove the greater than sign only use =

Comment: Your database field`(created_at)` and `$request->input('deposit_at_from'))` format should be same

Comment: the format is deposit_at_to=2020-02-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys but i figure it out, this is what works for me for getting range:

```
  $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->input('deposit_at_from')) 
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->input('deposit_at_to'));
  })
```

if you wonder the laravel ver is 5.6,

Thank you all :-))

Answer (score 0):

you are searching ranges, so it is logical you get multiple dates. also on input you need to have both dates set to limit lower and upper range limit. in your setup you need to send both 16/02/20 and 17/02/20 to receive records for 16/02/20.

so check that both values are available if you need to get a specific range.

```
if ($request->has('deposit_at_from') && $request->has('deposit_at_to') {
     $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->input('deposit_at_from'));
     $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->input('deposit_at_to'));

}
```

or just use one field for date filtering of you want a single date result and do raw filter:

```
$query->where(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) = '".date('Y-m-d', $request->input('deposit_date')."'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

remove greater than and less than sign so that you can get specific date result

```
function applyDepositOnRangeFilter($query, $request)
{
if ($request->has('deposit_at_from')) {
    $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '=', $request->input('deposit_at_from'));
    });
}


if ($request->has('deposit_at_to')) {
    $query->whereHas('deposits', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '=', $request->input('deposit_at_to'));
    });
 }
}
```